# Where can I find com.mathworks.jmi packages

Tags: java, matlab

I am using jdk 1.7.0_15. I am in need of using com.mathworks.jmi packages. but importing this package is giving an error like "...package doesn't exist". Searching in the internet, I haven't find any jar file named jmi. I am confused :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [matlabcontrol wiki page](https://code.google.com/p/matlabcontrol/wiki/JMI):

> The interface comes in the form of a jar file called jmi.jar distributed with MATLAB. It is found at matlabroot/java/jar/jmi.jar where matlabroot is the location of your MATLAB installation (on Windows it is located at matlabroot\java\jar\jmi.jar). For instance, on OS X with MATLAB R2009b it is located at /Applications/MATLAB_R2009b.app/java/jar/jmi.jar. What this jar contains depends exactly on what version of MATLAB is installed. All of the code in it has the root package com.mathworks.jmi, and there are a number of subpackages. Subsequent releases of MATLAB have seen additions to jmi.jar

Comment: thanks a lot. I found that jar on that location and added to my netbeans project.

Answer (score 1):

You also have to add the `jar` to the classpath. Use the `-cp` option on the command line.